# Copy values from one Mongodb collection to another by avoiding error 11000: 'Non-unique'

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aws-documentdb

This is what I have right now:

```
db.collectionFrom.aggregate([
    { $project: { _id: "$field5", field1: 1, field4: 1} },
    { $out : "collectionTo" }
]);
```

I try to copy only certain fields from `collectionFrom` to `collectionTo` (field1, field4, field5) one of which (field5) will be used as a key in the new collection.

The problem is that for `field5` the same value may exist more than 1 times in `collectionFrom` resulting in `error 11000: 'Non-unique'`.

`$out` stage cannot handle such cases for field5 (reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#index-constraints).

Is there any way to ignore (or remove) any possible duplicates? Maybe adding another stage in the aggregation in the pipeline? I do not want to delete any documents in `collectionFrom`.

**[Update]** Note: this should run on a DocumentDB instance on AWS (v3.6.0)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at `$merge` (it works like `$out`, but has more functionality).

Comment: Thank you @prasad_ for your answer. I forgot to mention that this should run on a DocumentDB instance on AWS (v3.6.0). Unfortunately, I found that ```$merge``` is not supported there. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html#mongo-apis-aggregation-pipeline